# Formula for the sequence: 0, 7, 19, 49, 91, 175, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, graphing-functions

I'm trying to write a code for finding the number of distinct lines in a 3d cube of size n. I started counting manually for $n = 1, 2, 3$ and $4$. I got the sequence: $0, 7, 19, 49, 91 ..$

Is there a simple function of n that governs this sequence?

Comment: Use OEIS: http://oeis.org/A090025

Answer (score 2):

It is shown in [OEIS A090025](http://oeis.org/A090025) where the formula $$a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)((\lfloor n/k\rfloor+1)^3-1)$$is given.  You can decide if you think that is simple.

Comment: What is moebius(k) ??

Comment: @Osama: It is referring to the [Mobius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

Comment: I mean fast in computation not necessarily simple